# How to remove shaded region of chatbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

```
background-color: rgba(78,93,108,0.25);
border-color: rgba(78,93,108,0.75);
border-width: 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
color: white;
outline: none;
padding-left: 8px;
```

This bit displays unusually. It creates a shaded region along the left and top side of the box. The CSS is constant along the whole border So I'm not sure why the region is shaded?

Comment: There's a perfectly good image uploader/host built right into StackOverflow, and we may need to see your HTML and more of the CSS. Best if you put together an actual HTML example of the issue instead of just screenshots.

Comment: You may want `border-style: solid;`. The default is inset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`border-style: solid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) vs `inset`

Use `border-style` to set the way the `border` is displayed.
Note in the example below, that an `inset` `border` shows the shadow you describe.

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: .2em solid grey;
}

div+div {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```